# this java script function is not working

Tags: javascript, html

**Can you please help me with this code this is showing no output**

*I just want to get the number of years left by a person before his/ her retirement
.
I have made an object that already has the values and when I use the third property  i.e, yearsuntilretire it, should the subtract 65 from their age and return the remaining age for then before retirement*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <script>

     function people(name,age){
         this.name= name;
         this.age = age;
         this.yearsuntilretire = yearsleft(); 
     }
     function yearsleft(){
            var numyears = 65 - this.age;
            return numyears;
     }

    var sip = new people("manda arpitha",19);

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     document.write(sip.yearsuntilretire();)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this.yearsuntilretire = yearsleft; ...

Comment: I think you forgot to return for the people() function. Try returning this.yearsuntilretire

Comment: Semicolon goes at the *end* of a line...

Comment: or move yearsleft to ```people.prototype```. and call ```this.yearsleft()```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to assign `yearsleft` to `yearsuntilretire`. Change `this.yearsuntilretire = yearsleft();` to `this.yearsuntilretire = yearsleft;`

```js
function people(name,age){
     this.name= name;
     this.age = age;
     this.yearsuntilretire = yearsleft; 
 }
function yearsleft(){
    var numyears = 65 - this.age;
    return numyears;
}

var sip = new people("manda arpitha",19);
document.write(sip.yearsuntilretire());
```

Comment: Change `document.write(sip.yearsuntilretire();)` to `document.write(sip.yearsuntilretire())`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be taking advantage of JavaScript prototyping here.

As well as being invoked with `new` instance constructors are usually capitalised so let's start there:

```
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
```

Then we add a function called `yearsUntilRetirement` to the prototype:

```
Person.prototype.yearsUntilRetirement = function() {
  return 65 - this.age;
}
```

Like you coded in your example we create a new object:

```
var sip = new Person('manda arpitha', 19);
```

But now all we need to do is call the function we attached to the prototype and, hence, this object.

```
console.log(sip.yearsUntilRetirement()); // 46
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7k7hqnd0/1/)**

In ES6, [classes were introduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) which made it slightly easier to deal with JavaScript object inheritence. Basically they're just "sugar" on top of the existing prototype system. This code performs the same as the code above:

```
class Person {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  yearsUntilRetirement() {
    return 65 - this.age;
  }

}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5nyf352r/3/)**